# creating multiple nested loops

Tags: nested-loops

I am trying to figure out how to efficiently figure out all the numbers which can be produced as a linear combination of some set, say the first few abundant numbers(12,18,20,24). The problem is the way I currently want to approach it is to run through all the numbers a*12+b*18+c*20+d*24 where the sum total doesnt exceed 100. Now I thought of 2 ways. A multiply nested while loop or one while loop which increments different things based on a conditional at the top of the while loop. My problem with both methods is that I don't know how many conditionals or nested loops I'll need until runtime as I don't know how many different numbers I'm going to be summing yet. Is there any way to write my program so that its nested n times for n number, or so that theres n conditions for n numbers.

Here is the outline of the switch block:

```
int count=1;
while(true){
    if(num2<smal){
        switch(count){
        case 1:
            a++;
            break;
        case 2:
            b++;
            break;
        case 3:
            c++;
            break;
        case 4: 
            d++;
            break;
      }
    }
    else {
        switch(count){
        case 1:
            if(a!=0){
                a=0;
                b++;
            }
            else{count++;}
            break;
        case 2:
            if(b!=0){
                b=0;
                c++;
                count--;
            }
            else{count++;}
            break;
        case 3:
            if(c!=0){
                c=0;
                d++;
                count--;
            }
            else{count++;}
            break;
        case 4: 
            break;
      }
  }
  //num is update here
  if(count==4){break;}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what language you're using, but if you don't know how many levels deep you might need to go, then you should consider recursion (as long as its not hundreds or thousands; you'll blow the stack).

In case you're not familiar with recursion, its where you have a function call itself. Here's a silly example.

```
Result doStuff(Stuff stuff, int level) {
    SubResult sr = null;
    if(stuff > 0) {
        sr = doStuff(stuff, level -1);
    }
    Result r = interesting_calculation(stuff, sr);
    return r;
}
```

Recursion can be tricky, but sometimes its the right tool for the job.

Comment: Wow ya probably should have been able to think of that. I'm using C++ btw. I think I might need to reinvestigate my approach though. As I feel like the recursion might quickly grow out of hand.

Comment: Wow I just realized that I was misreading the Project Euler question which is why I thought the question was so unbelievably hard. Lol the question as I now understand it seems almost trivial. I only need to find numbers which can be expressed as the sum of two numbers no more, and it doesnt include the multiples of those numbers which simplifies everything a whole lot. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: Just curious, can you link to the question?  Thanks!

Comment: http://projecteuler.net/problem=23. Enjoy! I've gotten quite addicted to the site and I really think its helping me develop my algorithm building techniques.